# How to filter Kafka messages before consumer consume in spring Kafka

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I am using spring Kafka in my project and I want to filter messages before consumer consumes based on key and value.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 15):

Yes in Spring Kafka you can filter messages before consumer consumes, there is an interface `public interface RecordFilterStrategy<K,V>` and a method in that interface `boolean filter(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<K,V> consumerRecord)`

so you need to override this `filter` method and if it returns false then the consumer will consume the message, otherwise, if it returns true then the message will not be consumed (it will be filtered out)

You can apply this filtration on message key, value, or headers

```
consumerRecord.key() // will return key of message
consumerRecord.value() // will return the message
consumerRecord.headers() // will return the headers
```

Example code:

```
 @Bean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConcurrency(Integer.parseInt(threads));
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(Long.parseLong(pollTimeout));
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.BATCH);
    
    if(true) {
        factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(new RecordFilterStrategy<String, String>() {
            
            @Override
            public boolean filter(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord) {
                if(consumerRecord.key().equals("ETEST")) {
                return false;
                }
            else {
                return true;
                 }
            }   
        });
    }
    
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of setting if (true) {...}

Answer (score 11):

adding to @Deadpool comments. It will work fine but it will not commit offset. so we will keep getting same message again but it will not consume. we need to set `factory.setAckDiscarded(true);` before setting `factory.setRecordFilterStrategy()` so that it will discard and commit offset.